# Upgrading Wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I looked for a specific answer to this question, but couldn't find it -- even on the WAMPSERVER site.  I'm sure I overlooked it.

I have Wampserver 2.0, with MySQL 5.0.51b, PHP 5.2.6, and Apache 2.2.8.  Would it be correct to install Wampserver 2.0i (MySQL 5.1.36, PHP 5.3, and Apache 2.2.11) over the older installation?  Would I lose data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll very likely want to uninstall it before installing the new version - might get port issues otherwise, and it's certainly neater. When uninstalling it does (or at least used to) ask if you wanted to keep your data, but I'd highly recommend copying that and backing it up somewhere before uninstalling. Once you've done that, just download & install the new version and you'll be rocking.

Not entirely relevant, but maybe take a look at XAMPP if you ever start to have WAMP problems - I switched because WAMP started to go wrong, not looked back since.

Comment: Thank you, and I'll definitely take a look at XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to uninstall existing wamp server. This will not remove your wamp >> www directory from your file system.

Now you need to install the new set up of the wamp server on same older location and it will automatically pick up your existing www directory and your data will be as it is.

But make sure to take back up of your www directory before doing this exercise.